# Why should I write all the Statements within Try-Catch?

Tags: code-reviews

My company head says that I must write all , i.e. ALL my code within Try-catch statements. Now, I can understand the 'better be safe than sorry' approach here, but isn't it too chicken-hearted to think that there will be an exception when the Labels are created, form's position is set. has there been instances where Exceptions in Such simple operations.

Comment: Just one try/catch around everything (e.g. in the main function in simple programs) would technically answer the question.  It would probably also make your boss throw an exception ;-)

Comment: This sounds like *buzz* terms by the same people that say that **all** SQL should be written as stored procedures for better performance.

Comment: Would you prefer, "If your code creates a run-time-error, you're fired." The game of chicken is fun until you see your opponent toss the steering wheel and brake pedal out the window.

Comment: @Jeff O - I actually believe that in software development the opponent is a freight train.

Comment: The best expression I've heard for this style of exception handling is "Nailing the corpse in the upright position", meaning, it leaves the application in an unexpected state.  Fail Fast, Fail Loudly is a much more modern approach, so you can actually work all the bugs out.

Comment: Is this a programming question or a management question?

Comment: @alex: Programming of course. Best Practices for coding

Comment: Are you sure? Even if you go to your company head armed with the best data, if you open the conversation with "you're too chicken-hearted" you probably won't get the results you desire.

Comment: The subject of the request is irrelevant... just saying "my company head says I should code..." is a big red flag.  It is micromanagement... this is not his job.

Comment: -1: This is vague (and maybe just argumentative) without a code sample to support what you're complaining about.

Comment: Try catches are must around codes which could fail due to reasons beyond your control. For example, a connection to a Database while the DB server is down. Other than that, putting them around every piece of code is indeed overkill.

Comment: Run some performance tests with the same code in and out of a try...catch block.  There's quite a performance hit when using try...catch, so we only use it when needed.

Comment: @MetalMiester - The impact on performance depends on the language and the particular implementation.  In C++, there generally is no performance hit unless an exception is thrown.

Comment: @CyprUS Sorry, but your company head is empty, there's no brain inside. Catching all exception in places you can't handle it is the single worst beginners mistake in Java (doing it is wrong in any language; in Java it's just more common because of the checked exceptions). Most of the time, letting the exception bubble up is the right thing. If you don't want you program to abort, then you need to make sure all exceptions are catched *somewhere*, but surely not in each method.

Comment: Put the try-catch body in another method, makes it less painful.

Comment: I bet that same head wants you to return an error code after you catch an exception.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> My company head says that I must write all, i.e. ALL my code within
>   Try-catch statements.

Well, this is a little overdone and just leads to noisy code. What are the benefits of having all the code (each method e.g.) written with a try catch handler? It just tells you there's an error to be fixed in most of the cases. Often times, the exception can and should be avoided in the first place.

A look on the stack trace is mostly sufficient to reveal the cause in your code, even if the faulting method does not perform the catch itself. There're times when developers corrupt stack-traces in exceptions, but that's far more often the case when you have lots and lots of exception handlers. Like anything: A little is good, but too much of it is poison.

Exception handling is indeed pretty simple:

Catch Exceptions

- whenever you need a special action as a reaction to the  exception
- whenever an exception would leave the program in an inconsistent state if unhandled

If you think about it, then there's most always just one place which is good to handle an occuring exception. And thus the handler should be in that place.

Many exceptions shouldn't even be thrown in the first place, so don't build your control structures around exception handling, rather try to avoid the possible occurence of exceptions whenever and wherever possible.

Remember to crash early when things go (unrepairably) wrong. Putting all the code in try-catch statements is absurd, but don't forget to report and log ALL exceptions.

Comment: +1 Not only leads this to noisy code, but even worse performance. When you put statements in a try block, the HotSpot Compiler won't be able to apply optimisations he otherwise would do.

Comment: @Oliver Weiler: Do you have a citation that explains what optimizations the HotSpot compiler doesn't do in try/catch blocks?

Answer (score 20):

> but isn't it too chicken-hearted to think that there will be an
>   exception when the Labels are created, form's position is set. has
>   there been instances where Exceptions in Such simple operations.

Absolutely yes! There's always a way for things to go wrong that you didn't foresee. And "chicken-hearted" is a ridiculous expression to use in this context; software development is not about proving your machismo through ignoring potential problems.

What *is* a valid question is whether it's *useful* for exceptions to be caught at the point where your coding standards say they have to. Your statement reads like you have to have try/catch block around every method body, and that is indeed absurd because you often cannot immediately do something useful with an exception, and that's actually the whole point of exceptions: that you can choose to let them propagate up the call stack to be dealt with at the appropriate point.

Comment: My apps know better than to throw exceptions or they'll get the beating of their life. Once they think you're chicken-hearted, they'll crash all over you.

Answer (score 10):

I would turn this the other way around. Yes, as a general rule exception handling is a good thing, but **can you actually handle every possible exception in a sensible manner at the point where it is caught?** Sometimes, particularly if you are not writing mission-critical software, it *is* better to simply crash and burn in some half-way-controlled manner when things go horribly wrong.

If you cannot be 100% certain that you can handle every single exception that might possibly be caught, you are probably better off writing some sort of general exception handler, wrapping the program's main loop in it - the exact mechanics of how to do that obviously depends on what language you are working in. There, log as much detail about the exception as you can, save program state (somewhere *other* than to whatever data store the user is currently working against - remember, it may all be corrupted at this point), and so on. Then, rethrow the exception and let the OS handle it however it sees fit. In this catch-all exception handler, [be prepared for catastrophic failure](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091113-00/?p=16043). Then, when the program is restarted, look to see if this state is in any way useful, and restore what can be salvaged if it is; and possibly offer the user to send a bug report back to you.

Comment: +1: Never catch an exception if you can't immediately deal with it correctly. (Alas, sometimes you have to trap it just to let it roam free again but tagged as a different type, as part of API coercing: I hate that.)

Answer (score 5):

Overall, using try/catch that much is deprecated, because catch block is so expensive from the point of resources. Try/catch usage reminds me of **risk management**. Risk management has two dimensions:

1. The probability of risk happening
2. The damage it can have

Now, if you go out of your house, a piano falling on your head somewhere while is so unlikelihood to happen (maybe 0.001%), but can kill you.

Exception handling is like that. Try block is not expensive. But catch block is really expensive, because it needs to create a table of stack trace, and doing other stuff. Therefore in making a decision about try/catch blocks, you should consider how many times you probably hit catch block. If among 10,000 usages, you only hit it 1 time, then use it. But if it's a form, and the user probably doesn't fill it correctly 50% times, then you should avoid putting a try/catch block into action there.

In places where the probability of exception occurrence is high, it's recommended to use `if {} else {}` blocks to avoid exception occurrence. 
For example, where you want to divide two numbers, instead of writing:

```
try
{
    int result = a/b;
}
catch (DivisionByZeroException ex)
{
    // Showing a message here, and logging of course.
}
```

you should write:

```
if (b == 0)
{
    int result = a/b;
}
else
{
    // Showing a message to user to change the value of b, etc.
}
```

Comment: +1 for using if/else to deal with "exceptions" that are basically just application logic.

Comment: If it's user-related, remember that computers are massively faster than people. An exception thrown in 50% of form submissions is still only likely to happen a few times a second even with many users.

Comment: I don't agree with you on the avoidance of try/catch blocks.  Constantly trying to anticipate exceptions is error prone, expensive in developer time, and makes your code harder to read. A loop that throws **a million** exceptions and catches them takes 500ms to run on my machine (vs. 1ms for an empty loop), which is not real-world performance difference in 99.99% of cases (and all UI code).  You should use exceptions except in cases where you know the performance penalty matters, because they make your code more reliable and let you assume that the previous code executed successfully.

Comment: @cosmic.osmo, do you retrieve the stacktrace or just catch it?

Answer (score 3):

You should use try-catch when appropriate, but please oh please don't catch all exceptions and not even log it.  At that point it's code smell and shoddy work.

Comment: +1 for logging.  Programs in the wild are black boxes.  When they fail, a log saying "Here's what happened" goes a very long way to solving the problem.  I've had errors in my programs that went unreported, and they were uncovered only after I found them in the log.

Comment: Right now I work with an app giving the very useful message “logging stopped after x MB of logging data” My problem comes later :-(

Answer (score 2):

I personally can't stand exceptions, they are VERY, VERY, VERY hard to handle correctly. And trying to uncorrupt the corrupt data is VERY, VERY, VERY hard!

- https://web.archive.org/web/20160313040605/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mgrier/archive/2004/02/18/75324.aspx
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040422-00/?p=39683
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050114-00/?p=36693
- https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/13/13/

If you don't call every function like:

```
try
{
    TrivialFunction();
}
catch(TypeAException)
{
    //MaybeFix
}
catch(TypeBException)
{
    //MaybeFix
}
catch(TypeCException)
{
    //NO FIX - CORRUPT DATA
}
catch(TypeDException)
{
    //NO FIX - UNKNOWN STATE
}
catch(OutOfMemoryException)
{
    //Try to fix this one! Destructors might allocate on their own ;)
}
catch(Exception)
{
    //Nothing to see here, move on, everything is OK ;)
}
```

There is no way you'll clean up correctly on every exit point. Exceptions are HARD!

The only good thing about exceptions is that if you don't catch them, the app crashes on unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Change to Swift.

A function cannot throw (directly or indirectly) unless it is declared to throw.

The compiler won’t allow you to use try/catch if there is nothing to catch.

The compiler gives you four choices when you call a throwing function;

1. The function crashes if it throws.
2. The function returns nil if it throws, which you must handle.
3. The error is thrown immediately by the caller if the caller is throwable.
4. You use try/catch with throw or rethrow to handle the exception

You will *never* use try/catch just because you were told to. You either realise that you don’t know how to handle and do the safest thing (crash). Or you use very simple handling, handling success or failure but not the reason if you don’t care. Or you pass it to the caller. Or you handle it *in a useful way*.

Unrelated to that: Exceptions should be exceptional. If my WiFi doesn’t work that’s a normal situation and not an exception. And programming errors are not exceptions. If function X detects it was called in the wrong way that should be a crash and then the incorrect code is fixed - you can’t handle programming errors, you fix them. So now the number of exceptions goes down.